How to get sub-schema from zod object schema
I have a schema like this:
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  email: z.string()
})

Later in the code, I want to validate just email. Is it possible to get somehow email schema like this: schema.getSubschema("email").safeParse(...)? I know I can separately define schema for an email but I would be more convienient to get it from the object schema.
EDIT
const saveHomeworkSchema = z
  .object({
    description: description,
    solution: description,
    video: file.optional(),
    images: files.optional(),
    domain: selectItem,
    theorems: theorems,
    definitions: definitions,
    tags: tags,
    isFree: z.any(),
    price: price,
    status: z.nativeEnum(HomeworkStatus),
  })
  .refine(
    (data) => data.solution || data.video || data.images?.length,
    'Musisz podać przynajmniej jeden format rozwiązania.'
  );



You can use .shape in this case:
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  email: z.string()
});
let email = 'xyz@xyz.com';

console.log(schema.shape.email.safeParse(email))

You can learn more here

Thank you! But what if I use refine()? Then shape does not exists :(

Could you please provide that example here?

I updated my question with the final schema

In this case i suggest you to build your schema separately and use it inside .object() for saveHomeworkSchema and with .shape function

thank you, I created another zod realted quesiton here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78465475/zod-check-if-any-of-object-properties-pass-validation

Your welcome :), always love to help ...
