zod - check if any of object properties pass validation
I have a schema like this:
z.object({
  name: z.string().min(3),
  email: z.string().min(3),
})

BUT I want to make it pas validation if at least one of these two properties pass validation. I wanted to do:
z.object({
  name: z.string().min(3),
  email: z.string().min(3),
}).refine((res) => res.name || res.email)

but there is still an error if any of the object properties fails and in refine I'm actually not checking if the valiadtion passes for name and email but I only check if they are defined. How to make it nice using zod?

Update your schema as below:
z.object({
  name: z.string().min(3),
  email: z.string().min(3),
}).or(
  z.object({
    name: z.string().min(3),
  }),
  z.object({
    email: z.string().min(3),
  }),
);

You can learn more here
